# java interface without implementation

Tags: java, interface, javafx-2

i recently bumps into this code below when exploring javafx, i see that **ObservableList** is an interface and there is no implementation of it, how can you use a variable of it ? obvious i am missing something here, can anyone point me to right direction?

> ```
>     List list = new ArrayList();
>
>     ObservableList observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
>     observableList.addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change change) {
>             System.out.println("Detected a change! ");
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: Huh? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html - That's the interface, and `FXCollections.observableList()` is returning an object that implements it to you.

Comment: are you sure it is not extending anything?

Comment: at least i don't see any one in the api documentation.

Comment: If the interface meets your needs, why bother with implementation details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code:

```
FXCollections.observableList(list);
```

means this method get a implementation of the interface, you can download the source to check it.

Comment: that could be the best explanation so far , i will go and check.

Comment: WHile you've already accepted this answer and started down this path ... that's exactly the wrong thing to do. The *point* of interfaces is that you don't care about the implementation (as an end user). You have a guarantee that the object being returned to you implements that interface; that's all you need to know to be able to use it.

Answer (score 6):

The `FXCollections.observableList()` method returns an instance of a class that implements that interface. You don't see the name of this class here, but you don't need to see it (or indeed, need to even know what it is.) This is the entire point of polymorphism -- of object-oriented programming: you, the client, only deal with the interface; it's somebody else's job to create the actual class, or set of classes, that implement it. If you get this one point, then you've got a handle on things.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use a variable with the type of an interface: you just can't *istantiate* it (no calling `new ObservableList()`), but any instance of a class that implements that interface is valid for that variable.

Comment: the problem is that they are calling a method of it, which kind of making you think you actually have a object here.

Comment: @dannynjust but what does "implements ObservableList" mean? That it must have the methods specified in the interface! That's why you can call the method on the object: you know that it *has* to have it, or else there would have been an error when compiling the implementing class.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not explain it better then here, have a look on this explanation: [using interfaces as variables](http://www.codestyle.org/java/faq-Interface.shtml#interfacevar)

Answer (score 0):

`FXCollections.observableList()` must return an instance of a concrete class, or `null`.

If the code you present actually works, the result cannot be `null` since in that case `observableList.addListener(...)` would throw a `NullPointerException`.

From this it follows that `FXCollections.observableList()` does return a non-`null` reference.

Consequently, the assumption that 'there is no implementation of [`ObservableList`]' is fallacious: there must be an implementation of `ObservableList` somewhere. You might not have access to it, but it certainly exists.

If you can, take a look at the source code for `FXCollections.observableList()`.

Answer (score 0):

yes , as the upper say .... the FXCollections.observableList()  method return an instance of a class that implements the interface of ObservableList...... t

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html

That's the interface, and `FXCollections.observableList()` is returning an object that implements it to you. You'll note in the JavaDoc that `ObservableList` extends `Observable` ... which is where `addListener()` comes from.

Answer (score -2):

The implementation is an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm).

Comment: There is absolutely no indication here that this is the case. It might be, or it might not, but we can't see the implementation so we don't know.

Comment: Nor would you care if it was. It's still an instantiation of something that implements the interface.

Comment: We can easily see the implementation, JDK is pretty much open-source. The said factory method chooses from two implementations, both are public classes.